# CN.setScreenSaverEnabled(false); and MediaPlayer

Tags: codenameone

Oddly when I play a video using `MediaPlayer` in a non-native way, after a few seconds (depending on the mobile phone settings) the power saving mode starts, which turns the screen off. This is an unwanted behavior, because when playing a video the screen must never turn off or dim. I don't understand if this is a Codename One bug or a feature, however it happens both on Android and iOS.

Apparently I fixed the problem using `CN.setScreenSaverEnabled(false);`. My problem, however, is that it doesn't work all the time. The following code sometimes makes the screen stay active, sometimes it doesn't. I don't understand why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

To better understand the following code, videoUrl is an HLS stream.

```
    private void playVideo(Form parent, String videoUrl) {
        CN.setScreenSaverEnabled(false);
        Form player = new Form(new BorderLayout());
        player.getToolbar().setBackCommand("Back", Toolbar.BackCommandPolicy.ALWAYS, e -> {
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.getMedia().cleanup();
            }
            CN.setScreenSaverEnabled(true);
            parent.showBack();
        });
        player.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(
                new SpanLabel("Stream will start playing automatically when it is live")));

        player.addShowListener(l -> {
            while (!Util.downloadUrlToStorage(videoUrl, "temp.m3u8", false)) {
                CN.invokeAndBlock(() -> Util.sleep(1000));
            }
            try {
                // note that we cannot play the locally downloaded m3u8
                Media video = MediaManager.createMedia(videoUrl, true, () -> {
                    // completion handler, it's invoked when the stream connection is lost
                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.getMedia().cleanup();
                    }
                    CN.setScreenSaverEnabled(true);
                    parent.showBack();
                });
                video.setNativePlayerMode(false);
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.getMedia().cleanup();
                }
                mp = new MediaPlayer(video);
                mp.setAutoplay(true);
                mp.setHideNativeVideoControls(true);
                mp.setMaximize(false);
                player.removeAll();
                player.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mp);
                player.revalidate();
            } catch (Exception err) {
                Log.e(err);
                ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Error loading straming");
            }
        });

        player.show();
    }
```

Comment: I suggest adding logging to make sure the right lines are reached. The logic here is for apps like facebook etc. you have video playing as you scroll but you don't want to disable the screensaver.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll try to log. So, do you confirm that I can use `CN.setScreenSaverEnabled(false);` and `CN.setScreenSaverEnabled(true);` in every point of my app code and every time that I need to enable or disable the power saving? Is it necessary to call it before showing a Form or isn't?

Comment: It should be possible to invoke it everywhere you want as far as I know. There's no restriction related to the current form showing.